# How to draw intersecting two lines on a plane?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

[image]

I tried to draw linear graph on a plane with intersection (2, 1) as the above referring to the following website: http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots_unstable.pdf

But mine doesn't even appear. What should I add more or remove in the following code?

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}  
\begin{axis}[axis on top,title=Graphics Import]  
\addplot graphics  
[xmin=-3,xmax=10,ymin=-3,ymax=10,  
% trim=left bottom right top  
includegraphics={trim=12 9 12 8,clip}]  
{external2};  
\addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};  
\end{axis}  
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see any `\begin{document}`, even if I'm almost sure it won't solve your issue.

Comment: Yes. where is your `\begin{document}`. You have to add the package pgfplots using `\usepackage{pgfplots}`. something will definitely appear.

Comment: @ddas I added them in the code, but I haven't yet solved it.

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture} before \begin{document} can only lead to hell.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay, I moved \begin{document} before \begin{tikzpicture}. Anything else to correct my code?

Comment: What's the file `external2` you're trying to include? And why are you including an image in a plot?

Comment: It compiles fine for me. I changed one line to `{example-image}` since I do not have `external2` file. http://imgur.com/rzabCRe

Comment: @buzzee : is the solution ok for you? If yes, consider accepting it. If not, comment the solution, explaining why this answer is not satisfactory for you. (I hope we helped you (-: !)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any intersection code in your example. Are you sure this is the right example?

```
\documentclass{stanalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,ticks=none,xmin=-1,ymin=-2,ymax=3,
             xlabel=$x_1$,ylabel=$x_2$, samples =2,,no marks ]
  \addplot+[domain=0:3] {x-1} node[left,text=black] {$x_1-x_2=1$};
  \addplot+[domain=0:5] {2-0.5*x} node[below left,text=black] {$x_1+2x_2=4$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, following MWE works fine.

```
\documentclass{article}  
    \usepackage{tikz}  
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}  
        \begin{axis}[axis on top,title=Graphics Import]  
            \addplot graphics  
                [xmin=-3,xmax=10,ymin=-3,ymax=10,% trim=left bottom right top  
                includegraphics={trim=12 9 12 8,clip}]  
                {example-image};  
            \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};  
        \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image: Processed MWE]

The only modification is the name of the file you are calling on line 10: `example-image` (a default picture, that LaTeX uses) has to be changed according to your filename.